# Cassandra on multi node cluster -- nodes not linking to Seed

Tags: cassandra

Below mentioned is my Cassandra set up:

- 192.168.80.115 (Seed)
- 192..168.80.116 (Node1)
- 192..168.80.117 (Node2)
- 192..168.80.118 (Node3)

I have installed the Cassandra in all the nodes 
below mentioned is the configuration of the cassandra.yaml

```
cassandra.yaml - 192.168.80.115 (Seed)
======================================

    cluster_name: 'Test Cluster'
    initial_token: 0
    seed_provider:
        - seeds:  "192.168.80.115"
    listen_address: 192.168.80.115
    rpc_address: 0.0.0.0
    endpoint_snitch: RackInferringSnitch


cassandra.yaml - 192.168.80.116 (Node1)
========================================
cluster_name: 'Test Cluster'
initial_token: -4611686018427387904
seed_provider:
    - seeds:  "192.168.80.115"
listen_address: 192.168.80.116
rpc_address: 0.0.0.0
endpoint_snitch: RackInferringSnitch

cassandra.yaml - 192.168.80.117 (Node2)
========================================

    cluster_name: 'Test Cluster'
    initial_token: 4611686018427387904
    seed_provider:
        - seeds:  "192.168.80.115"
    listen_address: 192.168.80.117
    rpc_address: 0.0.0.0
    endpoint_snitch: RackInferringSnitch

cassandra.yaml - 192.168.80.118 (Node3)
========================================
cluster_name: 'Test Cluster'
initial_token: -9223372036854775808
seed_provider:
    - seeds:  "192.168.80.115"
listen_address: 192.168.80.118
rpc_address: 0.0.0.0
endpoint_snitch: RackInferringSnitch
```

When I start Cassandra and check the node status in the seed I am able to see only my localhost and not other nodes

## 192.168.80.115 Seed

```
Datacenter: datacenter1
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address    Load       Tokens       Owns    Host ID                               Rack
UN  127.0.0.1  96.98 KB   256          ?       deb3f882-1886-4e09-be08-21ebd7e99c8d  rack1
```

And status in the nodes are as bellow

## 192.168.80.116 Node 1

```
Datacenter: datacenter1
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address    Load       Tokens       Owns    Host ID                               Rack
UN  127.0.0.1  116.33 KB  256          ?       21a310ee-5652-4179-8b59-d1c7dcd538ee  rack1
Note: Non-system keyspaces don't have the same replication settings, effective ownership information is meaningless
```

## 192.168.80.117 Node 2

```
Datacenter: datacenter1
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address    Load       Tokens       Owns    Host ID                               Rack
UN  127.0.0.1  156.95 KB  256          ?       b64a5a17-21d0-4cf6-bbd6-1eff8d8feb93  rack1

Note: Non-system keyspaces don't have the same replication settings, effective ownership information is meaningless
```

## 192.168.80.118 Node 3

```
Datacenter: datacenter1
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address    Load       Tokens       Owns    Host ID                               Rack
UN  127.0.0.1  157.04 KB  256          ?       43a24dea-26cc-4094-9da7-2b26b8c5f7e5  rack1
Note: Non-system keyspaces don't have the same replication settings, effective ownership information is meaningless
```

Why I am not able to see  worker nodes in seed node status

Comment: Try to set rpc_address = listen_address. What is your Cassandra version ?

Comment: as doanduyhai suggested look into rpc_address documentation for version of your cassandra nodes - for example for cassandra 2.2 https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.2/cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml.html - usually it should be not 0.0.0.0

Comment: I am having exact same problem.

Did you find solution for this ???